# Comparing DATE value in Python3 MySQL (mysql-connector)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

for my BOT I'm using a DB to get and store some stuff. Now I wanna only output everything in the DB that is newer/after today. Thatfor I wrote this code, but it isn't working.

```
            ts = time.gmtime()
            tsy = str(ts[0])
            tsm = str(ts[1])
            tsd = str(ts[2])

            todaysdate = tsy + '-' + tsm + '-' + tsd

            selDBcmd = "SELECT UT, SJ, HW FROM `homework` WHERE DATE(UT) >= '%s';"
            cur.execute(selDBcmd, (todaysdate))
            msg = 'homework:\n\n'

            selDBc = cur.fetchall()


            await client.send_message(message.channel, selDBc)
```

Does anyone has got an idea why its anyway outputting all of the DB data, and not only them where the date is after todays one?

I'm not as new to python, but to this mysql-connector thing in python

Comment: And maby the code isn't the best and cleanest one you can do/use

Comment: Are you sure `todaysdate` ends up in `YYYY-MM-DD` format? (Also, I'm not familiar with python libraries. Are the `'`'s needed around the %s? Some libs take care of them for you.) Oh, someone had a problem similar to this the other day... have you tried changing `(todaysdate)` to `(todaysdate,)`?

Comment: As a side note, if `UT` is a timestamp or datetime, `UT >= 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'` should be much faster (especially if `UT` is indexed); applying functions to field values in conditions is a performance killer.

Comment: now I've got `now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` then `selDBcmd = "SELECT UT, SJ, HW FROM homework WHERE UT >= '%s';"
                cur.execute(selDBcmd, (now))` but it isn't working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO here is the answer I found out after some more `trial and error` working

```
ts = time.gmtime()
tsy = int(ts[0])
tsm = int(ts[1])
tsd = int(ts[2])


selDBcmd = "SELECT UT, SJ, HW FROM `homework` WHERE UT >= '%s-%s-%s';"
cur.execute(selDBcmd, (tsy, tsm, tsd))
```